# How to create a custom Dynamic QR Code woocommerce payment gateway?

Tags: php, json, wordpress, paypal, visa

I would like to know how I can create a `Dynamic QR Code woocommerce payment gateway plugin`. Customers will be able to make payment using a Mobile App by scanning the code generated on the checkout page. It uses `mVISA`.

I have both Request and Response code provided the bank including `carback urls`. How can I combine the them into a plugin?

Answer (score 0):

PayPal does not have QR code integration process. You have to turn to technical support of Woocommerce for the further checking.